# How to query different databases from different vendors using VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net

I'm writing an application that should be able to query different databases from different vendors (Oracle, Sybase, SQL Server, MS Access).

Is there any tool that performs this for C# or VB.Net ? something like UnityJDBC ?

I would like to avoid creating different interfaces that communicate with different SQL structures to query databases.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a pretty far fetched dream to me!

Comment: It already exists for Java... http://www.unityjdbc.com/doc/multiple/multiplequery.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is built into .NET out of the box. However, simple web searches proves that it is possible to use LINQ to all of these

Oracle: http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm

Sybase: http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1056609

Access: http://forums.asp.net/t/1542443.aspx

SQL Server (there are a lot of resources, here's a comprehensive one): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/215712/LINQ-to-SQL-Basic-Concepts-and-Features

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's a good start. "LINQ to Entities" seems to do it, the problem with that is it converts only linq queries to SQL queries (according to database type : oracle, sybase...) In my case I have a plenty of SQL queries already written (test files) and aparrently converting SQL queries to Linq queries is not possible. Thank you though

Comment: If you need to convert between SQL syntax and LINQ syntax, there are tools. Linqer, for one, found at http://www.sqltolinq.com/downloads seems to work ok. I don't see an option for vb.net however just c#.